XIAO 24GHz mm wave sensor not working with I2C OLED display
I am trying to make a project using an I2C OLED display, XIAO ESP32-C3 board and a XIAO 24GHz mm wave sensor
Both the OLED and the sensor are working separately, but when both are connected to the ESP32, I think they are blocking each other.
Program code:
#if defined(ARDUINO_SEEED_XIAO_NRF52840_SENSE) || defined(ARDUINO_SEEED_XIAO_NRF52840)
#error "XIAO nRF52840 please use the non-mbed-enable version."
#endif

#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <mmwave_for_xiao.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>

#define SCREEN_WIDTH 128 // OLED display width, in pixels
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 64 // OLED display height, in pixels

// Declaration for an SSD1306 display connected to I2C (SDA, SCL pins)
// The pins for I2C are defined by the Wire-library. 
// On an arduino UNO:       A4(SDA), A5(SCL)
// On an arduino MEGA 2560: 20(SDA), 21(SCL)
// On an arduino LEONARDO:   2(SDA),  3(SCL), ...
#define OLED_RESET     -1 // Reset pin # (or -1 if sharing Arduino reset pin)
#define SCREEN_ADDRESS 0x3D ///< See datasheet for Address; 0x3D for 128x64, 0x3C for 128x32
Adafruit_SSD1306 display(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, &Wire, OLED_RESET);

// Define the SoftwareSerial object, D2 as RX, D3 as TX, connect to the serial port of the mmwave sensor
SoftwareSerial COMSerial(D2, D3);

// Creates a global Serial object for printing debugging information
#define ShowSerial Serial

// Initialising the radar configuration
// Seeed_HSP24 xiao_config(COMSerial, ShowSerial);
Seeed_HSP24 xiao_config(COMSerial);

Seeed_HSP24::RadarStatus radarStatus;

void setup() {
  COMSerial.begin(9600);
  ShowSerial.begin(9600);
  delay(500);

  ShowSerial.println("Programme Starting!");

  xiao_config.disableEngineeringModel();
}

void loop() {
  int retryCount = 0;
  const int MAX_RETRIES = 10;  // Maximum number of retries to prevent infinite loops

  //Get radar status
  do {
    radarStatus = xiao_config.getStatus();
    retryCount++;
  } while (radarStatus.targetStatus == Seeed_HSP24::TargetStatus::ErrorFrame && retryCount < MAX_RETRIES);

  //Parses radar status and prints results from debug serial port
  if (radarStatus.targetStatus != Seeed_HSP24::TargetStatus::ErrorFrame) {
    ShowSerial.print("Status: " + String(targetStatusToString(radarStatus.targetStatus)) + " ---- ");
    ShowSerial.println("Distance: " + String(radarStatus.distance) + "  Mode: " + String(radarStatus.radarMode));
    display.setTextSize(1);             // Normal 1:1 pixel scale
    display.setTextColor(SSD1306_WHITE);        // Draw white text
    display.setCursor(0,0);             // Start at top-left corner
    display.println(F("Hello, world!"));
    display.display();
  }
  delay(200);
}

// Parsing the acquired radar status
const char* targetStatusToString(Seeed_HSP24::TargetStatus status) {
  switch (status) {
    case Seeed_HSP24::TargetStatus::NoTarget:
      return "NoTarget";
    case Seeed_HSP24::TargetStatus::MovingTarget:
      return "MovingTarget";
    case Seeed_HSP24::TargetStatus::StaticTarget:
      return "StaticTarget";
    case Seeed_HSP24::TargetStatus::BothTargets:
      return "BothTargets";
    default:
      return "Unknown";
  }
}

I am getting this in the serial monitor:
13:16:03.010 -> Guru Meditation Error: Core  0 panic'ed (Load access fault). Exception was unhandled.
13:16:03.010 -> 
13:16:03.010 -> Core  0 register dump:
13:16:03.010 -> MEPC    : 0x42001808  RA      : 0x420017fa  SP      : 0x3fc95f00  GP      : 0x3fc8ca00  
13:16:03.042 -> TP      : 0x3fc88c10  T0      : 0x4005890e  T1      : 0x00400000  T2      : 0x00000000  
13:16:03.042 -> S0/FP   : 0x3fc8d620  S1      : 0x3fc8f000  A0      : 0x00000000  A1      : 0xffffffff  
13:16:03.042 -> A2      : 0x00000000  A3      : 0x000019bb  A4      : 0x00000000  A5      : 0x00000000  
13:16:03.042 -> A6      : 0xfa000000  A7      : 0x00000003  S2      : 0x3fc8f000  S3      : 0x00000000  
13:16:03.074 -> S4      : 0x00000000  S5      : 0x00000000  S6      : 0x00000000  S7      : 0x00000000  
13:16:03.074 -> S8      : 0x00000000  S9      : 0x00000000  S10     : 0x00000000  S11     : 0x00000000  
13:16:03.074 -> T3      : 0x3fc96ffc  T4      : 0x00000000  T5      : 0x00000000  T6      : 0x00000000  
13:16:03.074 -> MSTATUS : 0x00001881  MTVEC   : 0x40380001  MCAUSE  : 0x00000005  MTVAL   : 0x00000008  
13:16:03.106 -> MHARTID : 0x00000000  
13:16:03.106 -> 
13:16:03.106 -> Stack memory:
13:16:03.106 -> 3fc95f00: 0x00010000 0x00000000 0xffffffff 0xfafbfcfd 0x00ff0004 0x03040001 0x00000102 0x7909a3a7
13:16:03.106 -> 3fc95f20: 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x3fc8d620 0x420018b0 0x00000005 0x3fc8d9c4 0x00000013 0x42003b76
13:16:03.106 -> 3fc95f40: 0xfafbfcfd 0x00630002 0x01020304 0x7909a3a7 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x42006c20
13:16:03.106 -> 3fc95f60: 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x40387b8a 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000
13:16:03.138 -> 3fc95f80: 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0xa5a5a5a5 0xa5a5a5a5 0xa5a5a5a5
13:16:03.138 -> 3fc95fa0: 0xa5a5a5a5 0xbaad5678 0x00000160 0xabba1234 0x00000154 0x3fc95dd0 0x000001f7 0x3fc8e044
13:16:03.138 -> 3fc95fc0: 0x3fc8e044 0x3fc95fb4 0x3fc8e03c 0x00000018 0x45604ed1 0x56ad7ff4 0x3fc95fb4 0x00000000
13:16:03.138 -> 3fc95fe0: 0x00000001 0x3fc93fa4 0x706f6f6c 0x6b736154 0x337e7700 0x00922b98 0x00000000 0x3fc95fa0
13:16:03.170 -> 3fc96000: 0x00000001 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x3fc8fcc0 0x3fc8fd28 0x3fc8fd90



Is this crash dump the only monitor output or are there other strings sent by the program before the crash?

yes for first time we have "Programme Starting!" printed
then crash dump and reboot in a loop

If both hardware extensions work alone but not together, this may be a power supply issue. What is the supply of the display? A decoupling capacitor may be required here, because the little ESP-C3 does not have any bulk capacitors on board.

Just now tried with different power supply for oled , with common ground
still no luck
and this is remaining console output
ESP-ROM:esp32c3-api1-20210207
Build:Feb  7 2021
rst:0x3 (RTC_SW_SYS_RST),boot:0xc (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
Saved PC:0x40048b82
SPIWP:0xee
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fcd5820,len:0x1058
load:0x403cc710,len:0x8a8
load:0x403ce710,len:0x2fa0
entry 0x403cc710
Programme Starting!


So it ist not the supply then. Can you spread around some more println() to narrow down how far is comes in loop()? If you work with the Arduino IDE you can install the ESP Exception Decoder tool, is helps a lot in such cases.

Not related to the problem, but I think using SoftwareSerial is not necessary. One HardwareSerial channel would be more elegant and should also work with the original 250 kBit of the radar module: Serial2.begin(9600, SERIAL_8N1, D2, D3);

Download ESP Exception Decoder to trace down which line of code causes it. If you still can't solve it yourself, edit your post and provide the output of the exception trace. And you are using ESP32, you don't need SoftwareSerial, you can replace it with Serial2.

I have tried , with SPI oled , its working fine , dont know what's happening with i2c display.
What I suspect is some addresses are conflicting somewhere

The error seems to mean that you have some sort of NULL pointer exception.
There is something odd with that statement from your code
// Creates a global Serial object for printing debugging information
#define ShowSerial Serial

This is NOT what this code is doing. You are not creating a global object here.
that #define statement means that "ShowSerial" will be replaced by "Serial" by the C preprocessor before compilation. And nothing else.

This define is common in this kind of code. It is correct, in that it is an idiom on this platform. A weird idiom all right.

Dont know , this code without oled code is working fine ,
and with mm wave and oled connected I tried to search for I2C device address ,
then I am getting no device found

In the future, it will help to write it in C++, not in some weird mix of C preprocessor, C, and C++. This is not the source of your problem, but good habits are best learned early. A lot of the "Arduino" code out there teaches antipatterns that should be unlearned asap.
Preprocessor defines should not be used for constants or aliases. Modern C++ provides constructs precisely for such uses. Those constructs are subject to more error checking during compilation, and they also express your intent better. Namely:

constexpr int name = value is the idiom for compile-time integral constants
constexpr auto & newName = oldName is the idiom for giving existing objects different names

// [...]

constexpr int SCREEN_WIDTH = 128; // OLED display width, in pixels
constexpr int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 64; // OLED display height, in pixels

// Declaration for an SSD1306 display connected to I2C (SDA, SCL pins)
// The pins for I2C are defined by the Wire-library. 
// On an arduino UNO:       A4(SDA), A5(SCL)
// On an arduino MEGA 2560: 20(SDA), 21(SCL)
// On an arduino LEONARDO:   2(SDA),  3(SCL), ...

constexpr int OLED_RESET = -1; // Reset pin # (or -1 if sharing Arduino reset pin)
constexpr int SCREEN_ADDRESS = 0x3D; // See datasheet for Address; 0x3D for 128x64, 0x3C for 128x32

Adafruit_SSD1306 display(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, &Wire, OLED_RESET);

// D2 as RX, D3 as TX, connect to the serial port of the mmwave sensor
SoftwareSerial COMSerial(D2, D3);

// Uses the global Serial object for printing debugging information
constexpr auto & ShowSerial = Serial;

// Initialising the radar configuration
// Seeed_HSP24 xiao_config(COMSerial, ShowSerial);
Seeed_HSP24 xiao_config(COMSerial);

// [...]

The SCREEN_ADDRESS is not used in your code. It'd need to be passed to display.begin as the 2nd argument. So you can remove it if the display works OK.
Prefer using local variables over globals when the values are only needed locally. radarStatus should not be global:
void loop() {
  int retryCount = 0;
  constexpr int MAX_RETRIES = 10;  // Maximum number of retries to prevent infinite loops
  Seeed_HSP24::RadarStatus radarStatus;

  //Get radar status
  do {
    radarStatus = xiao_config.getStatus();
    retryCount++;
  } while (radarStatus.targetStatus == Seeed_HSP24::TargetStatus::ErrorFrame && retryCount < MAX_RETRIES);

  //Parses radar status and prints results from debug serial port
  if (radarStatus.targetStatus != Seeed_HSP24::TargetStatus::ErrorFrame) {
    // [...]
  }
  delay(200);
}
```


Thanks, this was just a example code from xiao, i was just testing to add a oled display to output sensor values , but no luck in resolving this issue.
